# Pass array as Post Value ASIFormDataRequest

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4

I am in need of passing an array to webservice.I have stored product identifiers into an nsmutablearray.and i want to pass this array to my php server. So i have the following thing.

```
__block ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
request.requestMethod = @"POST";
[request setPostValue:product_identifiers forKey:@"product_identifiers"];
```

When i NSLog my array,

```
 (
        "com.hoiuat.test.loves.oneweek",
        "com.hoiuat.test.loves.oneweek",
        "com.hoiuat.test.loves.oneweek",
        "com.hoiuat.test.loves.oneweek",
        "com.hoiuat.test.loves.oneweek",
        "com.hoiuat.4",
        "com.hoiuat.11",
        "com.hoiuat.3",
        "com.hoiuat.8",
        "com.hoiuat.6"
    )
```

the Php developer says they cant receive the parameter as Array.

Please let me know, how should i pass the array.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the web service requires, but you could pass it as a string delimited as follows:

```
NSString *postValue = [product_identifiers componentsJoinedByString:@"&"];
NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"product_identifiers=%@, postValue];

// this will generate the string:
// product_identifiers=com.hoiuat.test.loves.oneweek&com.hoiuat.test.loves.oneweek ...
```

Then setup the request with it like this:

```
[request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```